# Can the value of sin theta be greater than 1?

Tags: trigonometry

For example, is it possible for sin theta to be 1.06 or 1.2 under any circumstances?
Or is it possible for it to be exactly 1?

Comment: Of course not. The sinus won't be greater than the radius of the unit disc. Look how is defined the sine and cosine function w.r.t. the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry#/media/File:Sinus_und_Kosinus_am_Einheitskreis_1.svg)

Comment: It is possible over complex numbers.

Comment: Why exactly are you asking this question ? Just "randomly" ?

Comment: For real values of $\theta$ it follows immediately from $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$ that $\sin^2(\theta) \leq 1$ and $\cos^2(\theta) \leq 1$, and therefore that $|\sin(\theta)| \leq 1$ and $|\cos(\theta)| \leq 1$.

Comment: In geometry sin theta can never exceed 1. There are physical situations where a calculation suggests sin theta is greater than 1, and this is a sign that something different happens. (eg total internal reflection).

Answer (score 2):

No and yes.

**No:**
If you let $\theta$ be an angle in a right angled triangle, we know that $\sin(\theta)$ is equal to $\frac{\text{Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$. We know that the Hypotenuse is never shorter than the line Opposite the angle $\theta$, so this fraction can never exceed $1$.

**Yes:**
You can use complex numbers. So if $\theta$ is complex, then it can exceed $1$. For example, $\sin(1.57080 - 0.344701i) = 1.06$ (correct to 5dp at least).

Presumably you're at a stage where you aren't considering complex numbers, so the 'Yes' response here is a bit of a cheat. And I don't know of many cases where people go through explicit computations of $\sin(\theta)$ for complex $\theta$..

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of the sine function:

[image]

As you can see, $c > a$, so $\sin(\alpha) \leq 1$.